# Get data from a nested belognsTo

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a Modal that is x and x is connected with y who at the same time is connected with z now when I do a find('all') to the x I would like to get the values from the y modal and the z, so far I only been able to get the id but not the value

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check the `Containable` behavior. It will suit your needs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Answer (score 0):

You get data from other connected tables using CakePHP's [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) feature.

I'd suggest reading the above linked part of the Cookbook as it explains how Containables work within the first few lines. However, i a basic example for you would be:

`$this->X->find('all', array('contain' => 'Y'));`

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't see your response Eagle.

Answer (score 0):

The best method is to **debug** your variable. Then you know what data exactly you have and how to access it.

If the data you're trying to access is not there, then perhaps you should take a look at your model relations (belongsto,hasMany,hasOne).